# Mimic 'Paste' function into Input Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<input type=text>` that wants user to **paste** a URL into it. However, I want the site to provide a default URL in it, but changing the value isn't enough-- the site needs to mimic the **paste** event as if the user pasted the default URL in themselves.

So, is there a way to pseudo-paste a URL into an input text using jQuery? In the example code I have it so when *user* pastes an alert 'Hi' pops up, but what I want is when I hit play in the JSFiddle (or load the site in other words) there will be `www.example.com` pasted in (via the code) and 'Hi' will come up automatically in response.

https://jsfiddle.net/9c47r2qt/1/

```js
$("#test").bind("paste", function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" class="myInput" value="This is some default text" />
```

Edit: To be clear, I do not want data from the User's clipboard; in fact that would ruin things. I want the site to act as if the code is pasting data.

Comment: "hit play" - there is no play button anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I mean play in the JSFiddle. Editing question to clarify that now.

Comment: You may need special permissions. Have you tried `document.execCommand("paste")`?

Comment: `.bind` and `.unbind` is deprecated as well. Consider using `.on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function to assign a default `value` or `paste` (Current URL) when the site loads. It will show an alert *Pasted the default URL*

In your paste function you can use `.on` instead of `.bind` (its deprecated now). When the user actually paste something the alert shows *User Pasted Something*

To get the default current `URL` you can use `window.location.href` function.

Run snippet below to see working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Load the default URL
  $('.myInput').val(window.location.href)
  //Alert on load
  alert('Pasted the default URL')

  //Paste function - User
  $("#test").on("paste", function() {
    alert('User Pasted Something');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" class="myInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `trigger()`  the paste  event to run the event handler.

```js
$("#test").on("paste", function() {
  console.log('New value pasted:', this.value);
}).val('some new string').trigger('paste');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" class="myInput" />
```